# How to print out each three number (for Even number and Odd number)?

Tags: java

I want print output First Three Even number, After First Three odd number, After Second Three Even number After Second Three odd number

```
{ Like 
Even Number 
0 
2 
4  
Odd Number 
1 
3 
5
Even Number 
6 
8 
10
Odd Number 
7 
9 
11 }
```

Code:

```
public class OddAndEven {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=50;i++){
        if(i%2==1){
            System.out.print("Odd Number "+i);
        }
        if(i%2==0){
            System.out.print("     ");
            System.out.println("Even Number "+i);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: And the question is??

Comment: is it a homework or what? i like the line `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`

Comment: You can try @Peter Walser answer. Its working..

Comment: The answer has posted  ,you can try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

```
final int step = 3;

for (int s = 0; s < 50; s += step * 2) {

    System.out.println("Even number");
    for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
        System.out.println(s + i * 2);
    }
    System.out.println("Odd number");
    for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
        System.out.println(s + i * 2 + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: goes past 50 as per my old answer

Comment: nothing was said about a limitation in the original question, but it shouldn't be hard to check the numbers before printing them.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way

```
    for(i=0;i<=50;i = i + 6){
        System.out.println("Even Number");
        logIt (i);
        logIt (i + 2);
        logIt (i + 4);

        System.out.println("Odd Number");
        logIt (i + 1);
        logIt (i + 3);
        logIt (i + 5);

    }

private void logIt (int i) {
   if (i <= 50) System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: start from `0` according to question. and giving idea is better than answering such questions.

Comment: It print upto 54 need only 50. can you correct it ASAP.

Comment: Very nice and simple answer. +1

Comment: Thanks Hanky and Mustafa

Comment: There is no correction required @newuser. A programmer should be able to update the required loop limit on their own, if they cant, they shouldn't have even asked here. This isn't a paid job

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I know its not a paid job. But we must show the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public static void main(String str[]){



        final int step = 3;

        for (int s = 0; s < 50; s += step * 2) {

            System.out.println("Even number");
            for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
                int val=(s + i * 2);
                if(val<=50)
                System.out.println(val);
            }


            System.out.println("Odd number");
            for (int i = 0; i < step; i++) {
                int val=(s + i * 2 + 1);
                if(val<=50)
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }
 }
```

**Output :**

```
Even number
0
2
4
Odd number
1
3
5
Even number
6
8
10
Odd number
7
9
11
Even number
12
14
16
Odd number
13
15
17
Even number
18
20
22
Odd number
19
21
23
Even number
24
26
28
Odd number
25
27
29
Even number
30
32
34
Odd number
31
33
35
Even number
36
38
40
Odd number
37
39
41
Even number
42
44
46
Odd number
43
45
47
Even number
48
50
Odd number
49
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you like this clean version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int value = 4; value <= 50; value += 4) {
        print(value++, "Even");
        print(value++, "Odd");
    }
}

private static void print(int value, String prefix) {
    System.out.println(prefix + " number");
    for (int diff = 4; diff >= 0; diff -= 2) System.out.println(value - diff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a producer:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    OddEvenSequenceProducer producer = new OddEvenSequenceProducer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        System.out.println(producer.next());
    }
}

private static class OddEvenSequenceProducer {

    private final int step = 3;
    private int run;
    private int i;
    private boolean odd;

    public int next () {

        int value = (run * step + i++) * 2 + (odd ? 1 : 0);
        if (i == step) {
            i = 0;
            if (odd)
                run++;
            odd = !odd;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TrazenjeBrojeva 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int j=0, k=1;
    for(;k<50;)
    {
        for(int firstLoop=0;firstLoop<3;firstLoop++)
        {
            if((j%2)==0)
            {
                if(j>50)
                {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Number is even: "+j);
                j+=2;

            }
        }

        for(int secondLoop=0;secondLoop<3;secondLoop++)
        {
            if(!((k%2)==0))
            {
                if(k>50)
                {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Number is odd: "+k);
                k+=2;

            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Only with if and for loops, it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Kotlin

```
fun numbers() {
    // 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26 ... 100

var odd = true    
var iteration = 3

for(i in 1..30){
    
    if (odd) {
        // print only odd numbers
        if(i%2 != 0){
         print("$i, ")
         --iteration
        }
        
    } else {
        // print only even numbers
        if(i%2 ==0){
           print("${i}, ") 
           --iteration
        }
        
    }
    if (iteration == 0) {
        odd = !odd
        iteration = 3
    }    
}
```

for JAVA

```
void numbers() {
    // 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26 ... 100

boolean odd = true;
int iteration = 3;

for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    
    if (odd) {
        // print only odd numbers
        if(i%2 != 0){
         print("$i, ");
         --iteration;
        }
        
    } else {
        if(i%2 ==0){
           print("${i}, ");
           --iteration;
        }
        // print only even numbers
    }
    if (iteration == 0) {
        odd = !odd;
        iteration = 3;
    }    
}
```